# Filling input fields with every way possible doesn't work 100% of the time Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

So im making a bot that creates account from a website.

This is the code to fill in the form inputs :

```py
    driver.get(activation_link)
    print(activation_link)

    # Fill the form
    first_name = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "firstName")))
    scroll_into_view(driver, first_name)
    first_name.send_keys("Giannis")

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "lastName").send_keys("Papadopoulos")
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "userName").send_keys(EMAIL)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys(PASSWORD)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass2").send_keys(PASSWORD)

    # driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#firstName').value = 'Giannis';")
    # driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#lastName').value = 'Papadopoulos';")
    # driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#userName').value = '" + EMAIL + "';")
    # driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#password').value = 'PASSWORD';")
    # driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#pass2').value = 'PASSWORD';")

    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#firstName').value = 'Giannis';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#lastName').value = 'Papadopoulos';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#userName').value = '" + EMAIL + "';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#password').value = 'PASSWORD';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#pass2').value = 'PASSWORD';")

    # Privacy Policy checkbox
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "body > div.footer-wrap > div.container > div.row > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.col-sm-7.col-md-6 > div > div:nth-child(8) > div.col-xs-8.control-field > div > label > input[type=checkbox]").click()

    # Submit button
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "body > div.footer-wrap > div.container > div.row > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div.col-xs-8.control-field > button").click()

    driver.quit()

    # Save account credentials
    with open("accounts.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(EMAIL + "\n")
    print("Account created")
```

filling in the text inputs doesn't work 100% of the time, it either fills in the whole form , or it doesn't type anything. For context the site i fill the form in comes from a link in an email, and i know that selenium has it's bugs with redirection of webpages. Also im using undetected_chromedriver so i can register for an account without being detected by cloudflare.

I've tried send_keys() , clicking the text box and the send_keys,  i've tried driver.execute() , driver.execute_script(). Nothing seems to work 100% of the time and im clueless to why.

I also changed the code to see of exception were thrown and added two print statements to see if the code ever reaches execution :

```py
    try:
        scroll_into_view(driver, activation_link)
        print(activation_link.get_attribute("href"))
        activation_link.click()


    # Fill the form
        print(1)
        first_name = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "firstName")))
        scroll_into_view(driver, first_name)
        first_name.send_keys("Giannis")

        print(2)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "lastName").send_keys("Papadopoulos")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "userName").send_keys(EMAIL)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys(PASSWORD)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass2").send_keys(PASSWORD)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"!{e}!")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#firstName').value = 'Giannis';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#lastName').value = 'Papadopoulos';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#userName').value = '" + EMAIL + "';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#password').value = 'PASSWORD';")
    # driver.execute("document.querySelector('#pass2').value = 'PASSWORD';")

    # Privacy Policy checkbox
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "body > div.footer-wrap > div.container > div.row > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.col-sm-7.col-md-6 > div > div:nth-child(8) > div.col-xs-8.control-field > div > label > input[type=checkbox]").click()

    # Submit button
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "body > div.footer-wrap > div.container > div.row > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div.col-xs-8.control-field > button").click()

    driver.quit()

    # Save account credentials
    with open("accounts.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(EMAIL + "\n")
    print("Account created")
```

the console output for this is

```
https://account.jetbrains.com/signup-complete/...
```

this is just the link from

```
print(activation_link.get_attribute("href"))
```

notice the two print statements `print(1)` and `print(2)` are not ever executed

the html for the form:

```html
<div class="form-horizontal clearfix">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="email" class="">Email&nbsp;Address</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field js-email">
                        kijof29801@chokxus.com
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="firstName" class="">First&nbsp;Name</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <input maxlength="100" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" autofocus="" class="form-control js-input-first-name" value="" required="">
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="lastName" class="">Last&nbsp;Name</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <input maxlength="100" name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control js-input-last-name" value="" required="">
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="userName" class="">Username</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <input data-contact="7bdrohtjrcpaq37iuh3wmyp3w" name="userName" pattern="^(?=.{5,100}$)([\w.-]+|^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$)$" id="userName" type="text" class="form-control js-input-username" value="" data-url="/username-availability?_st=tAbC82V2y8iebV0e1fA2M3uDhlD0GYF5WqHgqmlepV8XyB5Ykw-HnfHRl2KpEq6r" required="" oninput="try { if($(this).val().match(new RegExp(this.getAttribute('pattern')))) { this.setCustomValidity(''); } else { this.setCustomValidity('A username must contain only latin symbols (A-z), digits (0-9), or be a valid email address 5 to 100 characters long.'); } } catch(e) {}">
                          <p class="help-block">Latin symbols (A-z), digits (0-9) or a valid email address 5 to 100 characters long.</p>
                        
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="message" class=""></label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <div>Please make sure you choose a strong password, as your account will have access to your purchases.</div>
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="password" class="">Password</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <input autocomplete="new-password" name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" value="" required=""><div class="progress "><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 0%;"></div></div><span class="password-verdict"></span>
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field">
                        <div js-input-ids="password,pass2" class="password-stealth js-password-eye"><a><i class="icon icon-eye-close text-muted"></i></a></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label for="pass2" class="">Repeat&nbsp;Password</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <input autocomplete="new-password" name="pass2" id="pass2" type="password" class="form-control" value="" required="">
                          <br>
                        
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 control-field"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 control-label">
                        <label class=""></label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 control-field">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <label><input name="privacy" type="checkbox" value="true" required="">I have read and I accept the&nbsp;<a href="https://www.jetbrains.com/legal/docs/agreements/jetbrains_account.html" target="_blank">JetBrains Account Agreement</a></label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: try/catch your calls and add the exceptions(s) you receive to your post.  It might also help to include the HTML markup of the form fields you are targetting.

Comment: I added more context , but the html markup of the form is way to big to put in the question

Comment: remove the scroll and try again... (that shouldn't be needed)  You should also avoid putting tokens/passwords in your posts.  (I removed them just to be safe... ) You can get the HTML markup for the fields by right-clicking and choosing "inspect".  You can copy just the field(s) you are targeting to the clipboard and then paste them into your post.  I don't see anything that would prevent the code from reaching your print statements, so that's a little odd that you aren't seeing an exception.  I don't know python so maybe someone can help with getting the exception out.

Comment: the scroll is need because the element is hidden behind an ad and if selenium tries to click it it clicks the ad and throws an exception

Comment: put your webdriverwait after the scroll...

Comment: first_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, "firstName")
 scroll_into_view(driver, first_name)
 WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(first_name))
 first_name.send_keys("Giannis") sadly this still produces the same outcome

Comment: You need to check the exception... that'll tell you a lot.  You should also get the element again after the scroll... it's position relative to the window (viewport?) will have changed... not sure if that'll cause a stale element exception or not.

Comment: this is the exception : `</a> is not clickable at point (308, 919). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/8691100/TempMail_S2S_FixedFooter_ROS_0" name="google_ads_iframe_/8691100/TempMail_S2S_FixedFooter_ROS_0" title="3rd party ad content" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" role="region" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" srcdoc="" data-google-container-id="3" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;"></iframe>` which i think is pretty clear, also i did re-get the element still frozen execution

Comment: I would add a sleep after the scroll... it's going to try to get position and if the window is still scrolling that might cause an issue.  The exception is telling you that this ad iframe is on top of the item you are trying to click, but I suspect that it's just getting the element's position wrong because of the scroll.

Comment: the ad is not the problem , ive figured that part out , the problem is that the send_keys() method sometimes fills the fields and sometimes it doesn't